# Method to fetch react native sign In from firebase by react.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

I am building a react native Bus Schedule application signed in with firebase. And also a web browser react.js application to handle the multiple user data from firebase. All I'm trying to fetch is a sign In the method of react-native firebase through react.js. Is there any way I can fetch the react-native sign In user profile data through react.js.!?

[image]

I am building a react native Bus Schedule application signed in with firebase. And also a web browser react.js application to handle the multiple user data from firebase. All I'm trying to fetch is a sign In the method of react-native firebase through react.js. Is there any way I can fetch the react-native sign In user profile data through react.js.!?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the firebase web SDK. There are several ways to retrieve the provider info listed in the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the Native Authentication data from firebase through react.js. I can't find any solution from the above link you provided.! Is there another solution avilable?